# Pinescript to Python getting The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, trading, pine-script

I'm converting a Pinescript Indicator to python  to use it with pandas:

Here is pinescrip code:

```
RSI_Period = input(14,title='RSI')
SF = input(5,title='Slow Factor')
QQE=input(4.236)

Wilders_Period = RSI_Period * 2 - 1


Rsi = rsi(close,RSI_Period)
RsiMa = ema(Rsi, SF)
AtrRsi = abs(RsiMa[1] - RsiMa)
MaAtrRsi = ema(AtrRsi, Wilders_Period)
dar = ema(MaAtrRsi,Wilders_Period) * QQE


DeltaFastAtrRsi= dar
RSIndex=RsiMa
newshortband=  RSIndex + DeltaFastAtrRsi
newlongband= RSIndex - DeltaFastAtrRsi
longband=RSIndex[1] > longband[1] and RSIndex > longband[1]?
 max(longband[1],newlongband):newlongband
shortband=RSIndex[1] < shortband[1] and  RSIndex < shortband[1]?
 min(shortband[1], newshortband):newshortband
trend=cross(RSIndex, shortband[1])?1:cross(longband[1], RSIndex)?-1:nz(trend[1],1)
FastAtrRsiTL = trend==1? longband: shortband

plot(FastAtrRsiTL,color=red)
plot(RsiMa,color=yellow)
```

Now this is what I got so far in python:

```
RSIPeriod = 14
SF = 5
QQE=4.236
WildersPeriod = RSIPeriod * 2 - 1     

df['RSI'] = ta.RSI(df['Price'], RSIPeriod)
df['RSI_ma'] = ta.EMA(df['RSI'], SF)
df['ATRrsi'] = abs(df['RSI_ma'].shift(1) - df['RSI_ma'])
df['MaATRrsi'] = ta.EMA(df['ATRrsi'], WildersPeriod)
df['dar'] = ta.EMA(df['MaATRrsi'], WildersPeriod) * QQE
df['newshortband'] = df['RSI_ma'] + df['dar']
df['newlongband'] = df['RSI_ma'] - df['dar']
df['longband'] = 0.0
df['longband'] =  np.where( df['RSI_ma'].shift(1) > df['longband'].shift(1) and df['RSI_ma'] > df['longband'].shift(1),
                           max(df['longband'].shift(1) ,df['newlongband']), df['newlongband'])
df['shortband'] = 0.0
df['shortband'] =  np.where( df['RSI_ma'].shift(1) < df['shortband'].shift(1) and df['RSI_ma'] < df['shortband'].shift(1),
                           max(df['shortband'].shift(1) ,df['newshortband']), df['newshortband'])

df['trend'] = np.where(df['RSI_ma'] > df['dar'].shift(1), 1, -1)    
df['FastAtrRsiTL'] = np.where(df['trend'] == 1, df['longband'], df['shortband'])
```

And this is the error:
----> 4 df['longband'] =  np.where( df['RSI_ma'].shift(1) > df['longband'].shift(1) and df['RSI_ma'] > df['longband'].shift(1),
      5                            max(df['longband'].shift(1) ,df['newlongband']), df['newlongband'])
      6 df['shortband'] = 0.0

~\Anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **nonzero**(self)
   1571         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1572                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1573                          .format(self.**class**.**name**))
   1574 
   1575     **bool** = **nonzero**

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o). You need to (1) enclose your comparisons in parentheses and (2) use `&` rather than `and` in your first two `np.where` statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to create a python function which takes a QQE indicator from TradingView.
The input is a Pandas.DataFrame which needs to have the column 'Close' that contains the Close price of the candles.

You can ofcourse change the input to fit your own parameters and needs.

```
def QQE(_candles):
    #https://www.tradingview.com/script/tJ6vtBBe-QQE/
    Close = _candles.Close
    Fast=2.6180
    Slow=4.2360
    RSI=14
    SF=2
    
    def WiMA(src, length):
        MA_s = [0]
        for i, x in enumerate(src):
            MA_s.append( (x + (MA_s[i] * (length-1)))/length )

        return MA_s

    def crossovers(p1,p2):
        a = []
        for i in range(1,min(len(p1),len(p2))):
            if p1[i] < p2[i] and not p1[i-1] < p2[i-1]:
                a.append(True)
            elif p1[i] > p2[i] and not p1[i-1] > p2[i-1]:
                a.append(True)
            else:
                a.append(False)
        return a

    RSIndex = ta.ema(ta.rsi(Close, RSI, fillna=0), SF, fillna=0)

    TR = [0]
    for i in range(1, len(Close)):
        TH = RSIndex[i-1] if RSIndex[i-1] > RSIndex[i] else RSIndex[i]
        TL = RSIndex[i-1] if RSIndex[i-1] < RSIndex[i] else RSIndex[i]
        TR.append(TH - TL)

    AtrRsi= WiMA(TR, 14)
    SmoothedAtrRsi= WiMA(AtrRsi, 14)

    # FastQQE
    DeltaFastAtrRsi = [x*Fast for x in SmoothedAtrRsi]
    newlongband = [x - i for x, i in zip(RSIndex,DeltaFastAtrRsi)]
    longband = [0]
    for i in range(1,len(RSIndex)):
        if RSIndex[i-1] > longband[i-1] and RSIndex[i] > longband[i-1]:
            longband.append(max(longband[i-1],newlongband[i]))
        else:
            longband.append(newlongband[i])
    newshortband = [x + i for x, i in zip(RSIndex,DeltaFastAtrRsi)]
    shortband = [0]
    for i in range(1,len(RSIndex)):
        if RSIndex[i-1] < shortband[i-1] and RSIndex[i] < shortband[i-1]:
            shortband.append(min(shortband[i-1],newshortband[i]))
        else:
            shortband.append(newshortband[i])
    
    trend = [0,0]
    shortbandCross = crossovers(RSIndex, [0]+shortband)
    longbandCross = crossovers([0]+longband, RSIndex)
    for i in range(1,len(shortbandCross)):
        if shortbandCross[i] == True:
            trend.append(1)
        elif longbandCross[i] == True:
            trend.append(-1)
        else:
            trend.append(trend[i])
    FastAtrRsiTL = [longband[i] if trend[i] == 1 else shortband[i] for i in range(len(trend))]

    # SlowQQE
    DeltaSlowAtrRsi = [x*Slow for x in SmoothedAtrRsi]
    newlongband1 = [x - i for x, i in zip(RSIndex,DeltaSlowAtrRsi)]
    longband1 = [0]
    for i in range(1,len(RSIndex)):
        if RSIndex[i-1] > longband1[i-1] and RSIndex[i] > longband1[i-1]:
            longband1.append(max(longband1[i-1],newlongband1[i]))
        else:
            longband1.append(newlongband1[i])

    newshortband1 = [x + i for x, i in zip(RSIndex,DeltaSlowAtrRsi)]
    shortband1 = [0]
    for i in range(1,len(RSIndex)):
        if RSIndex[i-1] < shortband1[i-1] and RSIndex[i] < shortband1[i-1]:
            shortband1.append(min(shortband1[i-1],newshortband1[i]))
        else:
            shortband1.append(newshortband1[i])
    trend1 = [0,0]
    shortbandCross1 = crossovers(RSIndex, [0]+shortband1)
    longbandCross1 = crossovers([0]+longband1, RSIndex)
    for i in range(1,len(shortbandCross1)):
        if shortbandCross1[i] == True:
            trend1.append(1)
        elif longbandCross1[i] == True:
            trend1.append(-1)
        else:
            trend1.append(trend1[i])
    SlowAtrRsiTL = [longband1[i] if trend1[i] == 1 else shortband1[i] for i in range(len(trend1))]
    return FastAtrRsiTL, SlowAtrRsiTL
```